# Discord ping command for discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I had a ping command already in place but recently I've been getting 0.0 as the output. It might have been the rounding in this case but I have no traceback errors. Is there a way I can get my ping output to show up like this?
`0.123`

My code:

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong! {0}'.format(round(client.latency, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the round() or change the number 1 to something higher

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Pong! {0}'.format(client.latency))
```